# Objects returned by NSUserDefaults should be released or not

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I would like to know whether objects returned by NSUserDefault is in autorelease pool or am is suppose to release them, and how should i know that any given object is in autorelease pool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Items returned by NSUserDefaults are autoreleased.

Everything in the Cocoa framework adheres to the [Cocoa Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994). Learn those, and you'll be set.